# wxWidgets for Ada?

Tags: wxwidgets, ada

In Lua-scripting I found wxWidgets (wxLua) library very useful, so I'd wanted to found binding for Ada and GNAT Programming Studio 2010 (4.4.1) - does it exist at all and maybe somebody know how to link it with GNAT?

Only one I found is wxAda, which is about 5 years old and without any hyperlinks to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the URL you are probably looking for is [wxada.tigris.org](http://wxada.tigris.org/), but it says right there it is incomplete. Most likely that's the best you are going to get without doing the work yourself.

From the [discussion of his problems here](http://www.archeia.com/wxada-an-ada95-binding-to-wxwidgets.html) it looks like he had solvable issues.

Comment: Thanks again - I have loaded latest source of GWindows & GNATCom from SourceForge's svn and it works properly! (maybe one or two issues was but it's too easy to fix them even for ada-begginer) Btw, there are very useful examples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of wxAda and tbh, it's a dead duck as it currently stands. I am looking at the moment at a revival by generating the source automatically.

Luke.